# += on a Vector gives strange / wrong type errors

Tags: scala

I have a variable `v` that is a `Vector`, and I'm trying to add an element to it using `+=`. It complains that it expects a `String` instead of an `Int`:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_45).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> var v = Vector[Int]()
v: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector()

scala> v += 3
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(3)
 required: String
              v += 3
                   ^
```

Why does it expect a `String`? When I give it a `String` (which is ofcourse wrong), it says it expects a `Vector[Int]`:

```
scala> v += "three"
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]
              v += "three"
                ^
```

And when I give it a `Vector[Int]`, it again expects a `String`:

```
scala> v += Vector(3)
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]
 required: String
              v += Vector(3)
                         ^
```

Why does this happen?

I know I can add an element using `+:=`. But why can I not use `+=`, like for a `Set`?

Comment: Vector have no "+" method (lookup scaladoc), so compiler defaults to StringAdd -- it will try to concatenate two strings via + method: vector.toString and your right side argument, which is not automatically converted to String, hence it complains.

Comment: @om-nom-nom: You could make it an answer for Jesper to accept it.

Comment: But why does `Vector` not have a `+` method (it has `+:` instead), and why does `Set` have a `+` method but not `+:` - why is this not the same for `Vector` and `Set`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's go through this cases one by one:

```
scala> v += 3
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(3)
 required: String
              v += 3
                   ^
```

Here is the main problem that Vector have no `+` method, so compiler will [default to string concatination](http://bit.ly/K8NpXl) (which is highly criticized recently as a design flaw, by the way). The problem is that left side (vector) is convertible automatically to string (via Vector.toString), but right one is not.

```
scala> v += "three"
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]
              v += "three"
                ^
```

Here concatenation is ok, but you're trying to put result of type String to variable of type Vector[Int], which is why compiler complains. But if you define v as Any compiler will stop complaining:

```
var v: Any = Vector[Int]()
v += "foo"
// res1: Any = Vector()foo
```

Now, next case

```
scala> v += Vector(3)
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]
 required: String
              v += Vector(3)
                         ^
```

String concatenation again, and again, result of type String goes to the variable of type Vector.

Now, talking about **why Vector does not have the very same + operation**: ordinary Set have no notion of order, whereas Vector, and Seq in general have and + would be confusing: *do I add to the end or to the start?* So instead of implicit rule, you have to explicitly decide whether you use :+ or +:.

Comment: It is worth noting though that there a few exceptions, e.g. `mutable.Buffer` does use `+=` to append instead of `:+=`... In any case, everyone should just vote for [SI-194](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-194) IMO

Comment: @0__ Looks like voting is not possible anymore, since the issue has been closed.

Comment: First case: "The problem is that anything can be augmented with a + method that takes a String, but 3 is not a String."

Comment: SI-194 is now open again